# What is the condition to get a rampage in Dota 2

Tags: dota-2

In Dota 2 we need to kill 5 enemy heroes in a short time. But what is the exact time? Or do we need to kill each hero within 10 seconds from the previous one?

I don't find any official documentation on that.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/DotA2/comments/1rrf0b/how_do_multikills_ownage_and_rampage_work/) on Reddit, unfortunately without further source, it is a maximum of 17-18 seconds between kills.